# What Am I Doing Wrong? (Armature Issue, .blend included for reference)

Tags: armature, parent, error

Link to download .blend file is at bottom of post.

I am currently attempting to parent a rig that I made to a female figure that I am working on for animation practice. After selecting the figure, then the armature, and pressing control-P, I selected the option "with automatic weights" in the parenting menu, as per the tutorial I was watching on the subject. When I did this, however, an error was thrown up, explaining that a solution was not found for one or more bones. Googling this error, I saw that this is not an uncommon problem, and began checking solutions others had posted that worked for some people. None worked for me. Here are some relevant points, in case the solution jumps out at one of the more knowledgeable users here:

1. My mesh is currently a single object with no modifiers or materials applied.
2. My armature is pretty basic; since I am new to this, I am not trying to make anything too fancy yet, I want to get the basics down before trying for more advanced animations.
3. The figure itself, being a modified figure from Daz Studio, is fairly complex; lots of vertices to worry about.
4. While in the included blend file there are some doubled verts, because I accidentally uploaded an earlier iteration of the file, I have removed all doubles and tried again prior to asking; so far, no dice.

My question is two-fold: First, what am I doing wrong? And second, what steps should I take to prevent myself from getting this error in the future?

FemaleRigFail.blend Download Link: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=97767392906038212085